# Why does same variable in ViewModel and Fragment differ?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to achieve these steps in this order.

1. Populate my Room database with data.
2. Update list variable (in ViewModel) with current database content.
3. Access list variable (in ViewModel) from my Fragment.

After execution I get Toasts in this order

- 0 in MythFragment
- 5 in MythViewModel

What I expected was the same number of elements. Does it differ because of Coroutines? Do I have to use LiveData?

MythFragment.kt

```
class MythFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: MythViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_myth, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MythViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.populateMyths()
        viewModel.fetchFromDatabase()

        Toast.makeText(activity, "${viewModel.myths.size} in MythFragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show()
    }
}
```

MythViewModel.kt

```
class MythViewModel(application: Application) : BaseViewModel(application) {

    var myths = listOf<Myth>()

    fun populateMyths() {
        launch {
            val dao = MythDatabase(getApplication()).mythDao()

            if (dao.getRowCount() > 0)
                return@launch

            val mythList = listOf<Myth>(
                Myth("This is the myth 1", "This is the evaluation of the myth 1"),
                Myth("This is the myth 2", "This is the evaluation of the myth 2"),
                Myth("This is the myth 3", "This is the evaluation of the myth 3"),
                Myth("This is the myth 4", "This is the evaluation of the myth 4"),
                Myth("This is the myth 5", "This is the evaluation of the myth 5")
            )

            dao.insertAll(
                *mythList.toTypedArray()
            )
        }
    }

    fun fetchFromDatabase() {
        launch {
            myths = MythDatabase(getApplication()).mythDao().getAllMyths()
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "${myths.size} in MythViewModel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()
        }
    }
}
```

BaseViewModel.kt

```
abstract class BaseViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application),
    CoroutineScope {

    private val job = Job()

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = job + Dispatchers.Main

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        job.cancel()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I expected was the same number of elements. Does it differ
> because of Coroutines? Do I have to use LiveData?

Yes, every time you use `launch` you run some code on another thread. That's why you still have 0 elements in your `Fragment`. It's better to use `LiveData`, so you get notified whenever your data changes.

In your `ViewModel` you can do something like this:

```
private val _myths = MutableLiveData<Myth>() // keep the mutable one private
val myths: LiveData<Myth> = _myths // expose an immutable one

fun fetchFromDatabase() {
    launch {
        _myths.postValue(MythDatabase(getApplication()).mythDao().getAllMyths()) 
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "${myths.size} in MythViewModel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

And in your Fragment you observe changes to myths:

```
...
viewModel.populateMyths()
viewModel.fetchFromDatabase()
viewModel.myths.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { myths ->
    Toast.makeText(activity, "${myths.size} in MythFragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
})
```

You can make the above code more concise by using a `livedata` builder (requires the `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.1.0` or up dependency):

```
val myths = livedata {
    emit(MythDatabase(getApplication()).mythDao().getAllMyths())
}
```

Then there's no need to call `fetchFromDatabase()` anymore either.

Comment: Thank you. I wonder why you exposed the LiveData and keept the mutable list private.

Comment: It's a best practice. You let only your 'ViewModel' be responsible for updating the 'LiveData'. If you expose the 'MutableLiveData', then your 'Fragment' could modify it like viewModel.myths.postValue() what can result in bugs and makes it more difficult to test

Answer (score 1):

Since you are populating the database at the same time you are subscribing to the data stream, get query executes before your population is completed resulting in `0 in MythFragment`. When second time you fetch the data, it gives you the `5 in MythFragment` as data have already been inserted.

So, to avoid the concurrency either you can make the call sequential or you can use `Transactions` from `Room` with `LiveData` which ensures that data will be emitted only when all the query defined inside it are executed.

Comment: I thought so. That's why I tried `Thread.sleep(5000)` in `MythFragment.kt` after `viewModel.fetchFromDatabase()`. I expected if I wait 5 seconds the data will get populated, but it didn't. Do you know why?